# Identifying unique HTML element without attributes

Tags: javascript, html, events

In case if there are no attributes or any css properties associated between two similar tags(like anchor tags below), is there any internal property in them to distinguish between the two?

```
<html>
<body>
      <a>sample</a>
      <a>sample</a>
</body>
</html>
```

If suppose an event was triggered from one of the tags, assuming both have same event listeners attached to them, would any event property help to identify which triggered?

Comment: can you use the index of that element in node tree?

Comment: Use "this" inside event handler or event.target

Comment: Welcome!
If you can modify the code:
Most people would point you to adding classes and query selector.
I'd use the `id` attribute...

Answer (score 0):

Using either event.target or *this* as shown below would solve the problem:

```
    function eventHandler(event) {
        let elementFromEvent = event.target;

        let elementFromThis = this;
    }
```

Comment: if a click action on the element was recorded and had to be replayed back using an automation tool, it would need certain properties to make the click on the right anchor tag. How do i handle that case?

Comment: @zennedy_16. You can use the node index of the element. That index can be used to identify the element